# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./components/LoginPage"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, package.json

This my webpack.config file

```
import webpack from 'webpack'
import path from 'path'

export default {
devtool: 'inline-source-map',

entry: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js')
],
target: 'web',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
resolve: {
   extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
 },
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
    }]
}
};
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
      "name": "zresume",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon server/server.js --exec babel-node"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "d3": "^4.10.2",
        "express": "^4.15.4",
        "nodemon": "^1.12.0",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "react": "^15.6.1",
        "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.3",
        "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
        "react-router": "^4.2.0",
        "redux": "^3.7.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
        "open": "0.0.5",
        "webpack": "^3.6.0",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0"
      },
      "babel": {
        "presets": [
          "es2015"
        ],
        "env": {
          "presets": [
            "react-hmre"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

My index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage';

    class App extends React.Component {
        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <h1>El Juego Lindo</h1>
                    <div>
                    <LoginPage />
                    </div>

                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

LoginPage Component

```
import React from 'react';
    import { Button, Collapse } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import LoginForm from './LoginForm';

    class LoginPage extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
              onButtonClicked: false
          }
          this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
      }

      onButtonClick() {
          this.setState({
              onButtonClicked: !this.state.onButtonClicked
          });
      }

     render() {
       return (
         <div>
         <div> I love football!!!! </div>
         <Button className="footballButton" onClick={this.onButtonClick} bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" block>Football Lover</Button>
         <Collapse in={this.state.onButtonClicked}>
           <div>
             <LoginForm />
           </div>
         </Collapse>
         </div>
       );
     } 


    }

    export default LoginPage;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y60r7.png)

Hi guys I'm a pretty novice programmer, and I'm having trouble with my react components rendering. For some reason it is saying that it can't find the module. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the login page file extension?

Answer (score 1):

You should name your files ".js", not ".jsx"

If you must use ".jsx", you need to specify the file ending when importing:

```
import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage.jsx'
```

Otherwise, Webpack assumes you've used ".js"

Comment: I just switched the named the files .js instead of .jsx and I am still getting the same error message. Thanks for the prompt attention Sidney

Comment: Could you upload an updated screenshot of your filetree?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y60r7.png Here is a screen shot of my file tree

Comment: That's the screenshot from your question, right? I wanted to confirm that you renamed the correct files, specifically these: https://imgur.com/a/VbIIv. I would try removing the `resolve` key from your webpack config. I can't think of anything else that would affect module resolution...

Answer (score -1):

There is an issue with Webpack 3 and you have to add a `blank space` to the accepted extensions, like this.

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [' ', '.js', '.jsx']
```

but also i recommend to add an alias to avoid import your components with the `.` (dot), and also remove the previous workaround

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      'Components': path.resolve(__dirname, '/components')
    }      
}
```

Now you can import your Components like this

`import YourComponent from 'Components/Login'`

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/981

Also doble check that `babel-node` has some issues with ES6 module autoloading https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node

Comment: Hello OsDev, I put a blank space to the accepted extensions but I still got the same error message unfortunately. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Maybe an issue with `babel-node` loot at **ES6-style module-loading may not function as expecte**` https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node try to mount the webpack-dev-server module instead ;)

Comment: What do you mean by mount the webpack-dev-server? Thanks in advance!!